# Try to checkout a new branch, without actually checking it out

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a bash script, where I test to see if the git status is clean by checking out a new branch, if I can't do that, I know the status is not clean. However what would be convenient is to just attempt to checkout a new branch but not actually do it, something like:

```
git checkout --dry -b temp
```

alternatively, if there is a way to use git status to get an exit code that is non-zero if it's not clean, that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more explicit about what you mean.

It's possible to switch branches even if you have uncommitted modifications (sometimes): see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

It's *always* possible to *create a new branch* without changing commits, which is what `git checkout -b name` does (unless *`name`* names an existing branch, in which case the checkout fails).

You can have an index that is in an unmerged state.  The test for this is to use `git write-tree`: if it fails, the index is in an unmerged state.

You can have an index that has files that differ from the `HEAD` commit, but is not in an unmerged state, and you can have a work-tree that has files that differ from their `HEAD` and/or index copies.  Testing these is more complex.

You can have submodules whose status is interesting.

There are tests for several of these conditions in `git-sh-setup`, which is found in the git-core directory as located by `git --exec-path`:

```
. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup

require_clean_work_tree "$action"
```

This will print:

```
Cannot $action: You have unstaged changes.
```

or:

```
Cannot $action: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
```

(or both, in a more sensible fashion) and return a nonzero error code, as appropriate.